# Transition happens instantly even though, I have duration time

Tags: css, transition

Transition takes effect, but duration doesn't. How to fix the issue, and why does it happen?

Html

```
<article class="about-img">
  <div class="about-picture-container">
    <img src="./images/about-bcg.jpeg" alt="tea kettle" class="about-picture">
   </div>
 </article>
```

CSS

```
.about-picture-container {
  background: var(--primaryColor);
  border: 0.5rem solid var(--primaryColor);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  /* overflow */
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.about-picture-container:hover .about-picture {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Comment: you need the transtion on `.about-picture` not its parent

Comment: Please provide a snippet with your question to reproduce a problem related to HTML or CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the transition to one class `.about-picture-container` and applying the transform to another `.about-picture`.

Try changing your code to:

```
.about-picture-container .about-picture {
  background: var(--primaryColor);
  border: 0.5rem solid var(--primaryColor);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  /* overflow */
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.about-picture-container:hover .about-picture {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```